# Node.js request module global events

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible using [request](https://github.com/request/request) to capture the events that are fired at the start and end of a request? I would like to attach a global event handler to request so that I can count the number of requests in progress at any given time.

Rather than attaching `.on('response')` and `.on('end')` to every request call in my code, I'd like to centralize it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the request module and call the request using your wrapper.in node 6 you can use proxies.